# I am getting a Pipe Notifications bind failure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a SNOWPIPE based data ingestion on SNOWFLAKE(on Azure) to ingest data staged on AWS. When I try to create the PIPE, I get an error as below

```
Pipe Notifications bind failure "Integration cannot be null for Azure"
```

Can anyone please let me know why I am getting this error. I am doing the below steps

---CREATE AN EXTERNAL STAGE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE SNOWPIPE_SATGE URL = 'S3://MY-BUCKET/FILES';
```

---LIST THE FILES IN THE BUCKET

```
LIST @SNOWPIPE_SATGE
```

--- CREATE THE TABLE WHERE THE DATA FROM PIPE WILL BE LOADED

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHOOLS_TABLE(GEOID INTEGER, SCHOOL_ID VARCHAR, SCHOOL_NAME VARCHAR, LAT NUMBER(10,5), LONG NUMBER(10,5);
```

---CREATE THE PIPE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PIPE SNOWPIPE_FOR_SCHOOL_TABLE
AUTO_INGEST=TRUE
AS COPY INTO SCHOOLS_TABLE FROM @SNOWPIPE_SATGE
FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER=',' SKIP_HEADER=1);
```

This is where(pipe creation) the error is coming

Comment: Looks like a Storage Integration is required when creating an AUTO-INGEST pipe on Azure, even though the underlying stage is in AWS: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-pipe.html#optional-parameters Suggest trying to create a Storage Integration and using that in the object definitions (stage and pipe): https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html#create-stage

Answer (score 0):

Set the AUTO_INGEST to False and it will work.

```
AUTO_INGEST = FALSE
```